# Better alternative to translateY percentage?

Tags: javascript

I have sliding panel that (for mobile) covers the whole screen, on click it slides down and reveals the elements you've added to a map.

Currently have it sliding down 90% of the screen so that the logo and slide button (at the top of the panel) are still on screen poking out the bottom.

I've found this to be inconsistent on different devices especially as some have the browser URL box at the bottom. I'm fairly new to javascript but was wondering if there's a better alternative to the percentage way I'm doing it?

```
    document.getElementById('slideY').addEventListener('click', function() {
      var wrapper = document.getElementById('slidingDiv');
      if (wrapper.style.transform === "translateY(90%)") {
        wrapper.style.transform = "";
      } else {
        wrapper.style.transform = "translateY(90%)";
      }
    });
```